# positioning two sibling elements to be at same top without using position absolute

Tags: css

```css
#parent{border:1px, solid, black; background:#efefef; height:100px;}/*To indicate the parent*/
#child1{background:green;position:relative;width:60%;height:30px; left:5%;top:10px;}
#child2{background:rgb(9,9,9);position:relative;width:30%;height:50px;color:white;left:65%;top:10px;}
```

```html
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child1">This is child one</div>
  <div id = "child2">This is child two</div>
</div>
```

I would like the two elements to be the same top without using position absolute since the second element height changes dynamically and it affect another element below it.

Comment: Use `display: inline-block;` ?

Comment: Give `float:left` to .child1

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response but, both the two methods each have a flaw. for floating left any element below is now displayed above and right of the two elements, for  displaying inline-block, if the first element is having block children and grandchildren then the second element is not displayed on the desired top position, it is pushed down. I have decided to use position absolute for 2nd child and instead of using 'top' for the elements after it I use 'bottom'.

Comment: Could you improve your snippet so we can adapt the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: inline-block;` as follow :

```css
#parent {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #efefef;
    height: 100px;
} /*To indicate the parent*/
#child1 {
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    height: 30px;
    top: 10px;
}
#child2 {
    background: rgb(9,9,9);
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    top: 10px;
}
.aligned {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child1" class="aligned">This is child one</div>
  <div id = "child2" class="aligned">This is child two</div>
</div>
```

**Or** `float: left;` as mentionned by @Sujata Chanda, see below:

```css
#parent {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #efefef;
    height: 100px;
} /*To indicate the parent*/
#child1 {
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    height: 30px;
    top: 10px;
}
#child2 {
    background: rgb(9,9,9);
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    top: 10px;
}
.aligned {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child1" class="aligned">This is child one</div>
  <div id = "child2" class="aligned">This is child two</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I just removed the `left` property to your CSS, it is no longer required since the elements will be aligned. If you want some space between the two, I suggest you use `margin` property.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#parent{border:1px, solid, black; background:#efefef; height:100px;}/*To indicate the parent*/
#child1{background:green;position:relative;width:60%;height:30px; left:5%;top:10px;float: left;}
#child2{background:rgb(9,9,9);position:relative;width:30%;height:50px;color:white;left:65%;top:10px;}
```

```html
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child1">This is child one</div>
  <div id = "child2">This is child two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to both `divs`.

Remove `left:65%;` from second `div`.

```css
#parent{border:1px, solid, black; background:#efefef; height:100px;}/*To indicate the parent*/
#child1{background:green;position:relative;width:60%;height:30px; left:5%;top:10px;float:left;}
#child2{background:rgb(9,9,9);position:relative;width:30%;height:50px;color:white;top:10px;float:left;}
```

```html
<div id = "parent">
  <div id = "child1">This is child one</div>
  <div id = "child2">This is child two</div>
</div>
```